# AttributeError: module 'odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_template' has no attribute 'mako_template_env'

Tags: python, odoo

This Function works perfectly in odoo 13, but i am migrating the app to odoo 15 and the function is now throwing an AttributeError: module 'odoo.addons.mail.models.mail_template' has no attribute 'mako_template_env'

here's the function;

```
def render_doc(self, doctype):
        types = {'cert': 'Certificate', 'pol_doc': 'Policy Document',
                 'guarantee_cert': 'Guarantee Policy Certificate'}
        if doctype not in types.keys():
            raise UserError(_('Document must be of type cert or pol_doc'))

        prod_doc_ids = self.policy_id.product_id.product_doc_ids
        doc = prod_doc_ids.filtered(
            lambda c: c.doc_type == doctype) if prod_doc_ids else False
        if doc:
            body = doc.body
        else:
            body = f"<p><strong>{types[doctype]}</strong> is not yet \
                setup for <strong>{self.policy_id.product_id.name}.</strong>\
                Please contact the system administrator.</p>"
        return mail_template.mako_template_env.from_string(body).render({'object': self})
```

It seems odoo 15 dont have the "mako_template_env" or was it renamed? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [clean code about rendering in mail_template](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/a03f6483d6be83a81eac6e8f667ce317c8007dbe#diff-bd520efea06a5449c8694b54f5f7aa8587c929a5669ea0439bb9d5e38f8d29c8) , you will see that Odoo replaced `mako_template_env` with `jinja_template_env`in v14 and replaced [jinja with qweb](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/68182baff4bdf4b3bcc1f46b361f5a5b8ac9aa11) in v15:

You can use the `inline_template` rendering engine:

> We still want user to use dynamic variables for some char fields (eg.
> subject, from, to, ...). We made a new rendering engine called
> "inline_template" that will render an expression enclosed by `{{` and
> `}}`.

***Example:***

```py
self.env['mail.render.mixin']._render_template(
    template_src=body,
    model=self._name,
    res_ids=self.ids,
    add_context={'types': types}
)
```

It will return a dict (`{res_id: string of rendered template based on record})`